# Why does numpy.random.choice not use arithmetic coding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, random

If I evaluate something like:

`numpy.random.choice(2, size=100000, p=[0.01, 0.99])`

using one uniformly-distributed random `float`, say `r`, and deciding if `r < 0.01` will presumably waste many of the random bits (entropy) generated. I've heard (second-hand) that generating psuedo-random numbers is computationally expensive, so I assumed that `numpy` would not be doing that, and rather would use a scheme like [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) in this case.

However, at first [glance](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L949) it appears that `choice` does indeed generate a `float` for every sample it is asked for. Further, a quick `timeit` experiment shows that generating `n` uniform floats is actually quicker than `n` samples from `p=[0.01, 0.99]`.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : numpy.random.choice(2, size=100000, p=[0.01, 0.99]), number=1000)
1.74494537999999
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : numpy.random.random(size=100000), number=1000)
0.8165735180009506
```

Does `choice` really generate a `float` for each sample, as it would appear? Would it not significantly improve performance to use some compression algorithm in some cases (particularly if `size` is large and `p` is distributed unevenly)? If not, why not?

Comment: one of the great things about python is most of the packages can be easily found as open source so you can investigate these questions easily enough, it seems as though you have already answered your own question maybe, but you can see exactly how numpy.random.choice is implemented @ https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L805

Comment: Perhaps I should edit the title. The question is really why does it make sense to generate more random bits than you need.

Comment: that seems like a great issue you should file on the gitlab listed above and submit a MR to numpy for :)... then you can even say you contributed to a package used by millions (probably millions... maybe only 100's of thousands)

Comment: @JoranBeasley :) ok will do. I was only hoping some wiser soul would point out the error in my reasoning above

Comment: I honestly dont know ... random is close to a magic black box as far as im concerned ... and seems "fast enough" for me

Comment: Generating pseudo-random numbers isn’t particularly expensive with many decent RNGs, no. (I don’t know which one NumPy uses by default, though – is it PCG64 (fast)? Did that change recently?) But how would arithmetic encoding save on calls to the RNG?

Comment: Most of us can't answer "why" questions because we aren't developers and haven't followed all the development issues (going back 10-20 years).  But my guess is that no one has felt the need or interest to optimizing the performance of `choice` (either in the old or new versions).  I see a lot more examples (on SO) of uniform random floats and integers than uses of `choice.   "why" questions are borderline opinion questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since NumPy 1.17, the reason is largely backward compatibility. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914862/why-is-random-sample-faster-than-numpys-random-choice/62951059#62951059) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62309424/does-numpy-random-seed-always-give-the-same-random-number-every-time/62310046#62310046).

As of NumPy 1.17, `numpy.random.*` functions, including `numpy.random.choice`, are legacy functions and "SHALL remain the same as they currently are", according to [NumPy's new RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst), which also introduced a [new random generation system for NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html). The reasons for making them legacy functions include the recommendation to avoid global state. Even so, however, NumPy did not deprecate any `numpy.random.*` functions in version 1.17, although a future version of NumPy might.

Recall that in your examples, `numpy.random.choice` takes an array of `float`s as weights. An array of integer weights would lead to more exact random number generation. And although any `float` could be converted to a rational number (leading to rational-valued weights and thus integer weights), the legacy NumPy version appears not to do this. These and other implementation decisions in `numpy.random.choice` can't be changed without breaking backward compatibility.

By the way, arithmetic coding is not the only algorithm that seeks to avoid wasting bits. Perhaps the canonical algorithm for sampling for a discrete distribution is the Knuth and Yao algorithm (1976), which exactly chooses a random integer based on the binary expansion of the probabilities involved, and treats the problem as a random walk on a binary tree. (This algorithm uses, on average, up to 2 bits away from the theoretical lower bound.) Any other integer generating algorithm can be ultimately described in the same way, namely as a random walk on a binary tree. For example, the [Fast Loaded Dice Roller](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03830v2) is a recent algorithm that has a guaranteed bound on the average number of bits it uses (in this case, no more than 6 bits away from the theoretical lower bound). The Han and Hoshi algorithm (from 1997) is another of this kind, but uses cumulative probabilities. See also my section, "[Weighted Choice With Replacement](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Weighted_Choice_With_Replacement)".

Comment: Great answer. Upvoted. Just curious, is it not possible to include both a new version and old one for backward compatibility dependent on Numpy version?

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder if there would be any interest in a weighted choice implementation for numpy? (or if one is hidden somewhere already?)

Comment: @Ehsan: `numpy.random.Generator.choice` (the new version of `numpy.random.choice`) and other methods in `numpy.random.Generator` may have a different implementation in different NumPy versions.

Comment: Hmm, but why didn't they use (something like) it before that legacy decision? Are there reasons against using it? Like, is it not worth it because the overhead work takes more time than generating extra random bits would?

Comment: @superbrain:  You will have to ask the creator of NumPy.  I don't know the answer, and whatever answer I can give will be speculation.

Comment: @superbrain there will be overhead of course, but my guess is that there is a bound on the entropy of your RV, after which you start winning on performance. The question is where that bound would have to be, and given that bound whether its then worth taking the time to implement.